# What is the proper way to set up this integral to find the area bounded by the curves?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> Sketch the region enclosed by the given curves. Decide whether to integrate with respect to x or y. Draw a typical approximating rectangle. Then find the area.
>
> $$y = 2x^2, y = 8x^2, 3x + y = 5, x ≥ 0$$

Here is my drawing: http://www.webassign.net/waplots/d/a/986f170c68ee080b539049f410cbba.gif

If I'm integrating with in terms of x, I know I'm going to need more than one integral, but I don't know how to set it up. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this intended to be the region between the two parabolas, i.e., $2x^2\le y\le8x^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll use one integral from $x = 0$ to $x = \frac{5}{8}$, where $y = 8x^2$ intersects $3x + y = 5$, and another integral from $x = \frac{5}{8}$ to $x = 1$. Put together, this gives the expression
$$
\left[\int_{0}^{5/8} 8x^2 - 2x^2\,dx\right] + \left[\int_{5/8}^{1} (-3x + 5) - 2x^2\,dx  \right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use double integral,

the intersection points:

between $y=8x^2$ and $y=5-3x$ are at $x=-1$ and $x=5/8$

between $y=2x^2$ and $y=5-3x$ are at $x=-5/2$ and $x=1$

let's assume that we want $\text{d$y$d$x$}$

for $I_1$: when $y$ goes from $y=2x^2$ to $y=8x^2$ then $x$ goes from $0$ to $5/8$

for $I_2$: when $y$ goes from $y=2x^2$ to $y=5-3x$ then $x$ goes from $5/8$ to $1$

$$\underbrace{\int_{x=0}^{x=5/8}\int_{y=2x^2}^{y=8x^2}1\text{d$y$d$x$}}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int_{x=5/8}^{x=1}\int_{y=2x^2}^{y=5-3x}1\text{d$y$d$x$}}_{I_2}$$

$$=\int_{0}^{5/8} \left(8x^2 - 2x^2\right)\text{d}x + \int_{5/8}^{1} \left(-3x + 5 - 2x^2\right)\text{d}x = \frac{125}{256}+\frac{117}{256}$$

Comment: I think you may need to elaborate on this a bit more.